# What parts of a string stretch most when a wave passes through it?

Tags: waves

So there's a (transverse) traveling wave on an (ideal) string under tension.  Why does the stretching occur around zero displacement?  Why not at the crests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a string is pulled tight to allow a transverse wave to pass, there will be some tension everywhere, not just in the bits near the crests or the zeros. However, if you consider a sine wave as a distorted straight line, then you can see that the amount of distortion (stretching) will depend on the gradient of the line. Consider a line element of initial length $dx$ that is horizontal, and add a small vertical displacement $dy$ at one end. Keep the ends apart by the same horizontal distance $dx$; then the total length of the element is now $\sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = dx\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$

From this it follows that the stretching of the string is a function of the slope - and that the string will be more stretched where the slope is greatest. Which is, of course, at the zero crossings.